# eliminate entries in dictionary based on a certain value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to eliminate entries in dictionary a and key-values for MyList if the second value is 8. I am missing something though.

My code:

```
a = {
   'Mylist' : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    }
a = [x for x in a if a['Mylist'][1] != 8]
print a['MyList']
```

Desired Ouput:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping over the *keys* of `a`, not the sublists of `a['Mylist']`.

The following corrects just the one value:

```
[sublist for sublist in a['Mylist'] if sublist[1] != 8]
```

To do so for all keys in the dictionary, nest this in a dictionary comprehension:

```
{key: [sublist for sublist in value if sublist[1] != 8]
 for key, value in a.iteritems()}
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = {
...    'Mylist' : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
...     }
>>> [sublist for sublist in a['Mylist'] if sublist[1] != 8]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> {key: [sublist for sublist in value if sublist[1] != 8]
...  for key, value in a.iteritems()}
{'Mylist': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply this in whole dictionary, you can do this:

```
for k in a:
    a[k] = [ l for l in a[k] if l[1]!=8]

print a['Mylist']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {
   'Mylist' : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    }
a['Mylist'] = filter(lambda x: x[1] != 8, a['Mylist'])
print(a)
```

Result:
{'Mylist': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}

Comment: It would be good if you could add an explanation to explain your code as well. This will help not only the OP but future users.